# PHP: Значение переменной по умолчанию

Tags: php

Взять CGI переменную 'a', или если ее нет, то приравнять 10.

Мой вариант:

```
if ($_REQUEST['a']=='') $a=10; else $a=$_REQUEST['a'];
```

У кого есть вариант покороче ?

Comment: Можно назвать победителем ?:

$a=$_REQUEST['a'] or $a=10;

Comment: Самый короткий:

    $a=$_REQUEST['a']or$a=10;

Answer (score 3):

Тернарное выражение:

```
$a = ( $_REQUEST['a'] == '' ) ? 10 : $_REQUEST['a'];

//Можно и так:
$a = ( ( $a = $_REQUEST['a'] ) == '' ) ? 10 : $a;

//Или так:
$a = $_REQUEST['a'];
if ( $a == '' ) $a = 10;

//Не знаю насчёт PHP, в JS можно:
$a = ( $_REQUEST['a'] == '' && 10 ) || $_REQUEST['a'];
$a = ( ( $a = $_REQUEST['a'] ) == '' && 10 ) || $a;
$a = $_REQUEST['a'] || 10;
```

Убираем все необязательные пробелы:

1. 42
2. 36
3. 34
4. 44
5. 37
6. 22

Варианты 4-6 не подходят для PHP!!!

Comment: Трехчлен, отлично, но длинно

Comment: 1. Удобнее.
2. Быстрее.
у тернарного выражения  много плюсов, пользуйтесь)

Comment: Убираем все необязательные пробелы:

Ваше - 51, вариант 1 - 42, вариант 2 - 36, вариант 3 - 34, вариант 4 - 44, вариант 5 - 37

Что-же по вашему коротко?)

Comment: да.. третий вариант тоже продуманный, тоже использую, но думаю можно короче.

Comment: Варианты конечно забавные ;) но можно и короче.

Comment: @timka_s,

    $a = ( ( $a = $_REQUEST['a'] ) == '' && 10 ) || $a;
    echo $a; // 1

И это 

    $a = $_REQUEST['a'] || 10;

Читаем про приоритетность логических операций ;)

Comment: аа.. надо не || а OR

Comment: @Sh4dow, Варианты 4-6 не подходят для PHP ( но работаю в JS ), в JS - `||` возвращает первый почти не false аргумент

Answer (score 2):

```
// определяем функцию: 
// работает в т.ч. со свойствами объектов и неопределенными переменными
function v(&$var, $alt = false) { return !empty($var) ? $var : $alt; }
// и далее:
$a = v($_REQUEST['a'], 10);
```

Ну ок, пробуйте, но с этим - аккуратно ;)

```
$a = @$_REQUEST['a'] or $a = 10;
```

Comment: ммм.. функция.. тоже вариант.. а без функций ?

Comment: Добавил вариант.

Comment: а зачем @ ? да пожалуй это самый красивый, 
$a=$_REQUEST['a'] or $a=10;
сомневаюсь что можно короче.

Comment: Функцию добавьте в основной класс, еще спасибо скажете. Собака глушит "Warning: undefined index". В вашем изначальном коде этот варнинг тоже есть, кстати.

Comment: Для будущих поколений, поясню, что читается так:

($a = $_REQUEST['a']) or ($a = 10);

Comment: А еще по этому же принципу работает "or die", в частности

    defined('APPLOADED') or header('Location: /') && die();

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = @$_REQUEST['a'] ?: 10;
```

Comment: Если @ выкинуть, будет нотис, но с нотисом работает и на 3 байтика меньше, если все пробелы повыкидывать. Классно !
Интересно а короче будет ?

    $a=$_REQUEST['a']?:10;     // победитель чтоли ?
    $a=$_REQUEST['a']or$a=10;

Comment: Отказываться пора от _REQUEST в пользу _GET ;)

Comment: И у вас такое работает?

  > Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Comment: Да, работает. [Ternary Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Так у вас ничего нету при `true`...

У меня - вылетает с ошибкой парсинга...

Почитал... Ваш код работает только при PHP >= 5.3